# Hive sum query needed?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have data set like below:

---

### PIC_NUMBER|C_DATE|OR_QUANTITY

1|2017-03-01|10
1|2017-03-02|11
1|2017-03-03|12
1|2017-03-04|13
1|2017-03-05|14
1|2017-03-06|15
1|2017-03-07|16
2|2017-03-02|20
2|2017-03-04|13
2|2017-03-05|14
3|2017-03-02|5
3|2017-03-03|6
3|2017-03-05|7
3|2017-03-06|8
3|2017-03-07|9
4|2017-03-01|10
4|2017-03-02|11
4|2017-03-03|12
4|2017-03-04|13
4|2017-03-05|14
4|2017-03-06|15
4|2017-03-07|16
1|2017-03-08|20
1|2017-03-09|21
1|2017-03-10|22
1|2017-03-11|23
1|2017-03-12|24
1|2017-03-13|25
1|2017-03-14|26
2|2017-03-08|30
2|2017-03-09|31
2|2017-03-10|32
2|2017-03-11|33
2|2017-03-12|34
2|2017-03-13|35
2|2017-03-14|36
3|2017-03-08|30
3|2017-03-09|31
3|2017-03-12|34
3|2017-03-14|36
4|2017-03-08|20
4|2017-03-09|21
4|2017-03-10|22
4|2017-03-11|23
4|2017-03-12|24
4|2017-03-13|25
4|2017-03-14|26

And I want to sum OR_QUANTITY in a way that is exclude lesser date OR_QANTITY ,and sum will be for same PIC_NUMBER.
Example result set is:

---

### PIC_NUMBER|C_DATE|SUM_OR_QUANTITY

1|2017-03-01|252
1|2017-03-02|242
1|2017-03-03|231
1|2017-03-04|219
1|2017-03-05|206
1|2017-03-06|192
1|2017-03-07|177
2|2017-03-02|278
2|2017-03-04|258
2|2017-03-05|245
3|2017-03-02|166
3|2017-03-03|161
3|2017-03-05|155
3|2017-03-06|148
3|2017-03-07|140
4|2017-03-01|252
4|2017-03-02|242
4|2017-03-03|231
4|2017-03-04|219
4|2017-03-05|206
4|2017-03-06|192
4|2017-03-07|177
1|2017-03-08|161
1|2017-03-09|141
1|2017-03-10|120
1|2017-03-11|98
1|2017-03-12|75
1|2017-03-13|51
1|2017-03-14|26
2|2017-03-08|231
2|2017-03-09|201
2|2017-03-10|170
2|2017-03-11|138
2|2017-03-12|105
2|2017-03-13|71
2|2017-03-14|36
3|2017-03-08|131
3|2017-03-09|101
3|2017-03-12|70
3|2017-03-14|36
4|2017-03-08|161
4|2017-03-09|141
4|2017-03-10|120
4|2017-03-11|98
4|2017-03-12|75
4|2017-03-13|51
4|2017-03-14|26

Can we write recursive functions in hive for this aggregation ?

Comment: What exactly is recursive here? Looks like you want a windowing function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give the desired result

```
  select PIC_NUMBER, val1 , sum(OR_QUANTITY) from 
( select a.PIC_NUMBER,a.C_DATE ,OR_QUANTITY, 
case when (a.C_DATE >= temp.C_DATE ) then temp.C_DATE ELSE null END as val1 
from table_name a ,  table_name temp 
where temp.PIC_NUMBER = a.PIC_NUMBER  ) temp1 
where val1 is not null 
group by PIC_NUMBER ,val1
```

Comment: Hi ashish, we also need to give alias e.g. a.OR_QUANTITY to this query.

Comment: You can put alias like `select PIC_NUMBER, val1 , sum(OR_QUANTITY)  as alias_name from ` in the query